# Can we define conjugate points independent of the geodesics?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I find the definition of conjugate points on Wiki

> Suppose $p$ and $q$ are points on a Riemannian manifold, and $\gamma$  is a geodesic that connects $p$ and $q$. Then $p$ and $q$ are conjugate points along
> $\gamma$  if there exists a non-zero Jacobi field along
> $\gamma$  that vanishes at $p$ and $q$.

I notice that, for defining a pair of conjugate points, we need to choose a geodesic. So can we define the conjugate points using the following method?

> Suppose $p$ and $q$ are points on a Riemannian manifold. Then $p$ and $q$ are conjugate points if there exist a geodesic $\gamma$ that connects $p$ and $q$ and a non-zero Jacobi field along $\gamma$  that vanishes at $p$ and $q$.

or

> Suppose $p$ and $q$ are points on a Riemannian manifold. Then $p$ and $q$ are conjugate points if for any geodesic $\gamma$ that connects $p$ and $q$ there exists a non-zero Jacobi field along $\gamma$  that vanishes at $p$ and $q$.

Are these two definitions above equivalent? If not, what are the counterexamples? That is, can we find a Riemannian manifold $M$, two points $p$ and $q$ on $M$, and two different geodesics that connect $p$ and $q$ such that $p$ and $q$ are conjugate along one and non conjugate along another.

Comment: Consider 2 hemispheres joined by a long cylinder. Consider 2 antipodal points on the equator of the first hemisphere. They can be joined by multiple "short" geodesics going along the first hemisphere, but we can also construct a single "long" geodesic that goes along the cylinder, passes the opposite hemisphere, and returns along the cylinder to the antipodal point. The vanishing Jacobi field only exists for the first set of geodesics.

Comment: @user3257842
Thanks! Your example is pretty!

Comment: @user3257842: You should be a bit more careful. The metric you described is only $C^1$ and not $C^2$. Usually, in differential geometry one requires at least $C^2$-smoothness of metrics to ensure existence of curvature.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  True. The (scalar) curvature on the hemispheric parts of the manifold is $1$ while on the cylindrical parts it's $0$, resulting in discontinuity of the curvature at the equators. The Jacobi equation seems solvable even taking this discontinuity into account. 

I choose the example because of its simplicity.  Truth be told, the idea I started from was to just glue a disk to a hemisphere, but that'd be even worse: it wasn't even $C^1$ .